# Min-max selection - checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

please can you help me with my checkbox, because i used generator for create checkbox and all work but i need configuare min and max select for this checkbox in javascript. I used most thing for it and nothing work a i still can select all but i need only one check from three.

**Script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var limit = 1;
$('input.css-checkbox + label.css-label').on('change', function (evt) {
    if ($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
        this.checked = false;
    }
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<table style="border-spacing: 5px; border-collapse: separate;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_lang" id="check_cz" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="check_cz" class="css-label"><img src="http://terquil.cz/images/cz.png" class="img-flag" alt="CZ" /></label>

            </td>
            <td><h2>CZ</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_lang" id="check_en" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="check_en" class="css-label"><img src="http://terquil.cz/images/uk.png" class="img-flag" alt="EN" /></label>

            </td>
            <td><h2>EN</h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check_lang" id="check_de" class="css-checkbox" />
                <label for="check_de" class="css-label"><img src="http://terquil.cz/images/de.png" class="img-flag" alt="DE" /></label>
            </td>
            <td><h2>DE</h2></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
      position:absolute; z-index:-1000; left:-1000px; overflow: hidden; clip: rect(0 0 0 0); height:1px; width:1px; margin:-1px; padding:0; border:0;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
    padding-left:37px;
    height:32px; 
    display:inline-block;
    line-height:32px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    font-size:32px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
    background-position: 0 -32px;
}
label.css-label {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_c1a4f40d98f1c23d1ad84d2af9c314be.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

If you have any opinion how can i fix it so help me.

I try too this script for my code and it doesnt work too.

**Test Script: (dont work)**

```
$("input[name=check_lang]").change(function(){
    var max= 1;
    if( $("input[name=check_lang]:checked").length == max ){
        $("input[name=check_lang]").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        $("input[name=check_lang]:checked").removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
         $("input[name=check_lang]").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
});
```

or this (dont work)

```
jQuery(function(){
    var max = 1;
    var checkboxes = jQuery('input[type="checkbox"]');

    checkboxes.click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var set = checkboxes.filter('[name="'+ this.name +'"]')
        var current = set.filter(':checked').length;
        return current <= max;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with C#?

Comment: my bad sry i removed C# tag.

Comment: No worries mate, tag with care.

Comment: why don't you use radio button?

Comment: @RadekTarant, are you looking for something like at the max 2 items can be selected ? If that's so, I have a solution for you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a group of items that require ONE to be selected only then you should be using a radio type not a checkbox. That will take care of your issue. The default behavior of a radio button is to only allow one selection out of many. Then you don't even need your JS.

Comment: thx, its true. I forget that i can use simple way to radio button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this snippet:

- it uses `name` to identify the checkboxes if there are multiple on the page
- it gives you the `type=radio` effect

```js
$("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {
  var $checkbox = $(this);
  if ($checkbox.is(":checked")) {
    var more = "input:checkbox[name='" + $checkbox.attr("name") + "']";
    $(more).prop("checked", false);
    $checkbox.prop("checked", true);
  } else {
    $checkbox.prop("checked", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Checkboxes with Radio-Effect</p>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Check 1</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Check 2</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" />Check 3</label>
</div>
```